# using an array for an html table in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm getting undefined index errors on my blade when trying to take my array and plug the values into an html table structure.

I have the array looped and sending it to blade:

Controller

```
$result = array();
foreach($getItem as $Item){
    $result[$Item->item_id][] = $Item;
}

//returning to blade but not included here
```

Dumped array:

```
array:26 [▼
    11873 => array:2 [▼
        0 => {#407 ▼
          +"item_id": "11873"
          +"item_name": "Title"
          +"item_comment": "Item Title"
          +"item_type": "2"
        }
        1 => {#408 ▼
          +"item_id": "11873"
          +"item_name": "Instruction"
          +"item_comment": "Inst Comment"
          +"item_type": "2"
        }
]
```

Blade:

```
@foreach ($result as $id => $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $item['item_id'] }}</td>
        @if($item['item_name'] == "Title")
            <td>{{ $item['item_comment'] }}</td>
        @endif
        <td>{{ $item['item_type'] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

So with the dumped array structure, one issue is the fact that the 'item_type' should be at the high level with the id, and shouldn't be in each nested level. But other than that I get undefined index errors. Am I just looping incorrectly?

Comment: You are creating an unnecessary nesting level assuming that `item_id` is unique for each array element. Try changing `$result[$Item->item_id][] = $Item;` to `$result[$Item->item_id] = $Item;`

Comment: But when I do that it only shows one of the Item name and comment objects. That's fine for the item_type, but I still need all sets of item_name and item_comment

Comment: I see that you have multiple array elements with same `item_id`. Use your original array construction code and try the solution that I've posted as an answer.

Comment: Try the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `@foreach ($result as $id => $item)`, `$item` is an array and you need to loop over it as well.

```
@foreach ($result as $id => $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $id }}</td>
        @foreach($item as $subitem)
        @if($subitem['item_name'] == "Title")
            <td>{{ $subitem['item_comment'] }}</td>
        @endif
        <td>{{ $subitem['item_type'] }}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work but the only issue now is that I still get two of the 'item_type'. Is there a way to only get that at the id level and not within the subitems?

Comment: You have two items for the single ID. Which one do you want to get?

Comment: They are tied to the id so they are always the same, I only get two because I have an inner join for name and comments

Comment: In that case, I suggest you to apply a limit at your query level, otherwise inconsistencies will be there.